# Melhorar performance de select SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo uma tabela com 2 milhoes de registros e preciso pegar de 1000 em 1000, sei que posso usar o TOP, mas uso da forma abaixo pq preciso controlar a quantidade, exemplo: pego 1000 depois as proximas 1000, depois as proximas 1000 e assim sucessivamente, ou seja no lugar desse mil, é uma variavel, enfim esse é meu select:

```
select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cd_cpfcgc ASC)as Row from cad_cliente) as teste where teste.Row between 1 and 1000
```

Porem ao executar está demorando cerca de 20 segundos, existe alguma outra forma de melhorar a performance? pois ao rodar nos servidor está dando timeout pela demora.

Desde ja agradeço.

Comment: se quiser uma melhor análise precisa colocar na sua perguta a estrutura das tabelas e se elas tem índice. Somente vendo o *execution plain* é que pode ter uma ideia mais real do problema, se tem *table scan*, se falta index, as interações de loop.. coloquei isso na pergunta para ajudar na análise

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um índice na tabela pela coluna de ordenação:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_cliente_cpfcgc ON cad_cliente(cd_cpfcgc);
```

Answer (score -1):

Poderia tentar uma estratégia mais simples, utilizando o [`order by`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) em conjunto com `limit`e `offset` para fazer a paginação dos items de 1000 em 1000, neste caso a sua variável seria o valor `offset`. Para a `primeira página` o valor seria 0, na `segunda página` o seu valor para o offset seria 1000, na `terceira página` seria 2000 e assim sucessivamente.

```
SELECT * FROM cad_cliente ORDER BY cd_cpfcgc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Este código segue o padrão idiomático do [`T-SQL`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL). Que é um idioma sql da Microsoft.